# Iterating over for loop & apply np.union1d

Tags: python

I would like to do `np.union1d` by iterating over a for loop.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
arr = np.empty((1,), dtype=np.int32)
for i in range(2):
    arr = np.union1d(arr, data[df.iloc[i,7]])
```

`data` is a dictionary, from which I want to pull value based on keys defined in 8th column of my data frame `df`. Sorry, I won't able to provide you more details for `data` & `df` because of business confidentiality. After running this loop I'm seeing arr is showing empty array while `data[df.iloc[i,7]]` is generating array of around 10K size for each iteration. Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure, check that your code isn't actually something like this:

```
for i in range(2):
    arr=np.empty((1,), dtype=np.int32)
    arr=np.union1d(arr, data[df.iloc[i,7]])
```

If not, I'd debug in the following way

```
for i in range(2):
    new_arr = data[df.iloc[i,7]]
    print(type(new_arr))  # check that it's an array
    print(new_arr.shape)  # check that first dim > 1, second dim = 1
```

Once you get this working I'd also suggest initializing `arr = []` because `np.empty` initializes the array by placing a very very small value as a placeholder so it will be present in your final concatenated array!

Comment: no first way is not in my code.I will debug using the way you mentioned